# Executing a command line using php shell_exec() for initiating a camera on the server

Tags: php, shell, opencv, archlinux

I am using opencv for initiating the camera on my arch linux. Its getting initiated and works well when I actually do it from the command line on the server itself. 
I want to initialize it using php. I tried doing it using `shell_exec` from PHP.

My PHP file looks like:

```
<?php
$output=shell_exec('LD_LIBRARY_PATH=usr/local/lib ./a.out 0 2>&1 1>/dev/null');
echo $output;
?>
```

It gives this output:
`ERROR: capture is NULL`

I am running this through my windows web browser as a client and the opencv and the related files are on the server that is my arch linux.

I want to start the camera and capture images when I run this php file from the windows web browser, but when executed it throws the error as mentioned.

Comment: You're redirecting all output to /dev/null, so there'll be nothing returned.

Comment: ok...now i removed the /dev/null part...the error went off....bt still the camera is not getting started on the server(arch)....

Comment: Does the webserver user have the rights to execute that file?

Comment: yes....the server user can execute that....i did that through the server's terminal..executed the LD_LIBRARY_PATH=usr/local/lib ./a.out 0 from the terminal...and it works well...the camera gets initialized and the images are captured...also there is only single user...and its the admin so has the complete rights to execute...the problem is when i try to execute it using php shell_exec command..after it is run on the client it should initiate the camera on the server...thats what i expect to do using php..

Comment: in addition now i have given the php file the chmod 777 rights...just thought that it might have the permission problem...bt no use....stuck yet..

Comment: could you try to use absolute path for that LD_LIBRARY_PATH?

Comment: @fajran: sorry.. i dint get ur question...the path i have given is actual i guess...please get me the details about ur question...

Comment: Changing the php file's permissions will not affect the user ID that'll actually be executing your a.out progrma - it'll be the UID the webserver is running as.

Comment: @MarcB: as u said..it affects nothing..so now i just compiled other C program file..it was a simple addition program..and just executed it through php by putting in shell_exec('./a.out'); and got the output...so the a.out is executing well on the browser and showing the result..the problem persists with the camera openCV file and its execution.

Comment: How does this app access the camera? Your webserver's UID must have access to ALL resources that are being accessed. It's a long chain of things that have to happen right, and you're just scratching on the surface.

Comment: ok..now i have a file called capture.c built up using openCV that when executed from the command line...initiates the camera...captures the images after every 2 secs...and saves it into the server....now my client side has a page that refreshes every 2 secs giving me the latest image that is captured by the server side openCV file....so the client side browser helps me view the images in a stream....so it seems as a video...this is my application...for the client side to view images the server side must be initiated with the camera...

Comment: the thing i do with the terminal of the server...i want it to be done by the php file..thats where i am facing the problem..unable to initiate using php...:(

Comment: Sorry, I thought the working directory when you execute the command was incorrect. But looks like you can already execute the application although it's not working. So, nevermind :)

Comment: Try to execute your script in command line. For example, `php camera.php`, where camera.php es your script. If everything works as expected, than it might be an issue with permissions - web servers runs under the different user

Comment: thanks timur :)i guess its the permission problem. the process that executes the php is run by the apache server. that is the user is different mayb http. So now can any one please tell me about giving permission to the http as the admin STEPWISE...thank you.:)

Answer (score 0):

While this may work when you are SSHed into your server. The webserver user is most likely different than the user you login as. Popular user ids/groups that webservers run as on Linux machines are http, www-data, nobody, and others.

From this point you have two options.

1. You can make sure the script you are trying to run from PHP (and all of it's children, if any) is able to be run by the webserver user.
2. You can modify your /etc/sudoers file which gives the webserver user access to elevate permissions for that script only. (NOTE: This potentially opens up security holes so be careful).

To find out what user your webserver runs as execute this: `ps aux`
Take a look at the output and the first column in the output lists the user that that process is running at. Here's an excerpt of my webserver (nginx) on one of my boxes:

`www-data 26852  0.0  0.0  29768  3840 ?        S    Jun04   0:50 nginx: worker process`

You can see that nginx runs with the user www-data here. You can also execute the command with grep to help you find the process quicker. Grep will only show you those lines which match what you send to it. Here's an example: `ps aux | grep nginx`

Ok now that you know what user the webserver is running as, let's try giving that user access to the script. Let's say your script is `foo` and is located in `/usr/local/bin`. You would do the following commands:

`chown www-data /usr/local/bin/foo`

After changing ownership on the file try to rerun your command again from your PHP page and see if it works.

For completeness I also said you could give your webserver user sudo privileges to that file. To do that you would need to append the following line to the bottom of your `/etc/sudoers` file:

`www-data    ALL=    NOPASSWD: /usr/local/bin/foo`

Then your shell_exec command could switch to this:

`shell_exec('sudo /usr/local/bin/foo');`

Please keep in mind that doing this would allow your webserver user to run the script as `root` which is incredibly dangerous in a variety of situations. However, the camera may require elevated permissions to work. I'm not sure what the permissions requirements are on the camera setup you are trying to invoke.

Good luck. Hope this helps!